# How to specify path to SQLite in PDO driver?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

On a Centos6 SQLite 3.6 was installed by default. But I need one more version of SQLite 3.8 for PHP.  So I just downloaded 3.8 sources and compile it without make install. Now default version is 3.6 but I can launch 3.8 running it from directory where it was compiled. how can I specify for PDO to use not default version of SQLite, but use custom version compiled in user/local?

Comment: depends on how your particular pdo module was built...

Comment: We should read manuals for you - http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php?

Comment: Dsn prefix works to specify path to SQLite db file, not to specify path for a SQLite service

Answer (score 0):

See, there is no such thing like "SQLite service".
SQLite is only a file and a program to operate it. PDO_sqlite is such a program, and it has its own implementation of all the necessary routines, and, therefore, depends not on whatever else utilities. You can install 3.6, or 3.8, or delete both - it will not affect PDO even slightest.

Comment: Yep. It was a mistake to call it service. Now I have installed 3.6 and 3.8. SQLite 3.6 default and PDO is using 3.6 but I need to work with SQLite 3.8 via PDO without changing default version